# Kabini Radeon HD 8330 on Linux mint 17.2 Rafaela jumpy video

Tags: linux-mint, video, radeon

I have a Zotec zbox with the afore mentioned graphics card and I am running Linux mint 17.2 cinnamon on this machine. I have fglrx drivers installed version 2:15.200-0ubuntu0.6 and for the most part everything is smooth. However when I am watching a video or playing a game the video appears to stutter (not the sound).

Has any one else come across this issue or knows of a fix? (I have googled already)

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Check in /var/log/Xorg.0.log (or similar name) which driver you are effectively using. If you see a lot of lines with VESA, there is some problem who prevent fglrx to load.

Comment: i'll take a look

Comment: can't find any vesa warnings or errors in the xorg log

Comment: Not errors, but if you find a lot of lines with "VESA", it means that the VESA driver is used, instead of fglrx. VESA driver doesn't have acceleration, so you have jumpy videos